# " "init" is deprecated: first deprecated in ios 10.0 " warning message in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, warnings, avaudiorecorder

So I have a code to start recording audio and keep getting the above warning message. any help?

```
- (IBAction)recordStart:(id)sender {
    AVAudioSession *recSession1 = [[AVAudioSession alloc] init];
    [recSession1 setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    [recorder1 prepareToRecord];
    [recorder1 record];
}
```

Comment: I am not an expert for AVAudio, but one of the first Google hits for "AVAudioSession" is https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1631/_index.html which contains the sample code `AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];` – Is that what you need?

Comment: @MartinR yes thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation for `AVAudioSession` you will see that it is a singleton. You are not supposed to create your own instances. Use the `sharedInstance` method.

```
- (IBAction)recordStart:(id)sender {
    AVAudioSession *recSession1 = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [recSession1 setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    [recorder1 prepareToRecord];
    [recorder1 record];
}
```

The error you are getting is now there to ensure that you access the shared instance properly instead of attempting to create your own instance.